# how to condition data table checkbox if check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox, datatables

i dont know how to condition the checkbox inside the datatable. I want to condition if the checkbox in data table is check, i will insert it in my database, and if it is uncheck , i will delete it in database. I am using a codeigniter framework.

Here is my controller:

```
public function getalldocs() {
        $listdocs = $this->Admin_model->getdoctors();
        $data = array();
        foreach ($listdocs as $docs) {
            $row = array();  
            $row[] = $docs->user_fname;
            $row[] = $docs->user_mname;
            $row[] = $docs->user_lname;
            $row[] = '<input name="user_id[]" value="'.$docs->user_id.'" type="checkbox">';

            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(   
            "data" => $data,
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

here is my javascript, i manage to alert the value of user_id when i click the checkbox but i dont know how to condition it, wether it was check or checked and uncheck again. Here it is:

```
function show_docs() {
    $("#dataTables-docs").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    table =  $('#dataTables-docs').DataTable({ 
      "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_controls/getalldocs')?>",
              "type": "POST",
          },
          responsive: true,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          'bInfo': false,
          'paging': false
      });
}

$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

  var user_id = $(this).val();
  alert(user_id);

  });
```

Here is my view:

```
 <table id="dataTables-docs"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" aria-describedby="dataTables-material">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> 
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>                                               
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table id="dataTables-docs"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" aria-describedby="dataTables-material">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> 
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>                                               
                            <th><input type="checkbox" value="sdsd">Check</th>
                        </tr>
                      <tr> 
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>                                               
                            <th><input type="checkbox" value="sdsd">Check</th>
                        </tr>
                      <tr> 
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>                                               
                            <th><input type="checkbox" value="sdsd">Check</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

      if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      alert("Checkbox Is Checked");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Checkbox Is Not Checked");
    }


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Check with is(":checked") in jquery**

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

      if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      alert("Checkbox Is Checked");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Checkbox Is Not Checked");
    }


});
```

Comment: hello sir, this is what i've done: checking is working but uncheking with the value of the user_id is not working.

Here is the code: $('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var user_id = $(this).val();
      alert(user_id+"checkbox is check");
    }
    else {
      alert(user_id+"Checkbox Is Not Checked");
    }
  });

Comment: try // .on('change', instead of .on('click',

Comment: do i need to create another function for onchange? can you please edit your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    for(i = 0; i < $("input[type="checkbox"]").length; i++){
        if($(this).porp("checked")){
            //delete function
        }
    }
})
```